# SQL query table filtering

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a question regarding a query in MS Access. My database has **cooking recipes**, and what I have need is **a query that will return all the meals that can be made with the available ingredients.**

The involved relations:

`Ingredients`(**`Ingredient_name`**, `Quantity`)

`Contains`(**`Meal_name`**, **`Ingredient`**, `Ingredient_amount_needed`)

`Meals`(**`Meal_name`**, `Price`)

(Bolded are primary keys)

I know how to make a new table which will consist of meals, ingredients, needed quantity and available quantity. I can also add a condition (needed quantity < available quantity). However, **I need to filter all the meals which don't have ALL the necessary ingredients, even if it's just one.** 
For example, if I've got rows such as:

```
Meal        Ingr.        Needed qty Available qty
Pizza       Ham           50         100
Pizza       Cheese        100        1
```

The result of my query shouldn't show Pizza at all, because there's not enough cheese.

Comment: what are you trying to ask?

Comment: I'm trying to ask what the sql code for such a query would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have created the newtable as you have shown, the following query should work:

```
select Distinct Meal from NewTab NT
where not exists 
   (select 1 from NewTab where NeededQty>AvailableQty 
    and NT.Meal = Meal);
```

Comment: Please let me know if it serves your purpose?

Comment: For some reason this lists an empty table, even though it should work. I probably made some mistake, i'll recheck. Still, I understand what you tried to do and you've given me the idea so it should work eventually, thanks a lot.

Comment: OK, I have cross checked this part with sample data, it's working fine..All you need to do is create "derived table/temporary table" and put that in place of NewTab..!!